# Ionic & Google OAuth for mobile app and web site

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, oauth, google-plus, ionic3

I am having trouble using the [Google Plus authentication plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) in an Ionic app which talks to an API shared by our website.

In the Google Console I have three OAuth 2.0 client IDs, *example ids given*

- Android client (auto created by Google Service) *1.apps.google*
- iOS client (auto created by Google Service) *2.apps.google*
- Webapp *3.app.googles*

They all start with the same 12 digit number and end with "apps.googleusercontent.com".

According to [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth) I should be able to authenticate a mobile app and a website against the same API project by adding a scope setting that identifies the API's client id e.g. _scope:audience:server:client_id:3.apps.google_

```
this.googlePlus.login({
  'webClientId': '2.apps.google',
  'scope': 'scope:audience:server:client_id:3.apps.google'
})
```

I have been able to get a JWT returned from Google but when I decode it I find the **aud** value matches my webClientId setting when it should be the value from scope. As far as Ic an tell the only places that save the clientID persistently (as in not excluded by the .gitignore file that Ionic made) are config.xml

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="git+https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git">
    <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="google.apps.2" />
</plugin>
```

and package.json

```
  "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
    "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "google.apps.2"
  }
```

So, which clients IDs do I put where so that my mobile app can authenticate users against the same API that our web site is using?

Comment: Hope this helps to you:https://javebratt.com/ionic-google-login/

Comment: The first part of the tutorial is the steps I used to generate the client IDs but doesn't answer the set up with a mix of mobile app ad web site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be a change in the API's client id. Until now we've been using the full id, like this

```
1234567890-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

However, if we changed the API to use only the `1234567890` portion it accepted both the web and app clients, with of which are using their own IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus for both web and mobile

**Steps for Ionic integration :**

- Add Plugin & initialise / declare you plugin on app.module.ts

`$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=myreversedclientid
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus`

Note: When you're adding your plugin, you need to use **reversed client id** not forwarded client id (Follow My article: https://codesundar.com/create-reverse-client-id-for-google-login/)

- Import same plugin on the page, you're using & create an object for GooglePlus class

```js
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';

constructor(private googlePlus: GooglePlus) {

}
login(){
  this.googlePlus.login({})
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the setup I have already, and the JWT returned to my mobile app contains only the client ID (not reversed id) of my mobile app in both the azp and aud properties. The only way I can get the API to accept the idToken is if the aud matches its clientID and then it will differ from the web one.

Also, I don't like the idea of having to use the same plugin for mobile and web, this system should be able to work regardless of the language framework I use.

Comment: If you pass client id to:  this.googlePlus.login({webClientId: 'YOUR_FORWARD_CLIENT_ID' }), it'll generate you idToken; you can get idToken from success callback; but however, when you're adding plugin you need to use reverse client id without "quotes"